# How to make a foreign key with a constraint on the referenced table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Suppose I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE plugins (
id int primary key,
type text);

insert into plugins values (1,'matrix');
insert into plugins values (2,'matrix');
insert into plugins values (3,'function');
insert into plugins values (4,'function');

CREATE TABLE matrix_params (
id int primary key,
pluginid int references plugins (id)
);
```

This all works as expected but I would like to add an additional constraint that a matrix_param can only refer to the pluginid that has type 'matrix'. So

```
insert into matrix_params values (1,1);
```

Should succeed but

```
insert into matrix_params values (2,3);
```

Should fail.

A simple constraint for matrix_params does not work as it has no way of knowing what the corresponding type is in the plugins table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a CHECK constraint for this. You can't put a query in a CHECK constraint but you can call a function; so, we build a simple function that tells us if a `pluginid` is a matrix:

```
create or replace function is_matrix(int) returns boolean as $$
    select exists (
        select 1
        from plugins
        where id   = $1
          and type = 'matrix'
    );
$$ language sql;
```

and wrap that in a CHECK constraint:

```
alter table matrix_params add constraint chk_is_matrix check (is_matrix(pluginid));
```

Then:

```
=> insert into matrix_params values (1,1);
=> insert into matrix_params values (2,3);
ERROR:  new row for relation "matrix_params" violates check constraint "chk_is_matrix"
```

And the FK takes care of referential integrity and cascades.

Comment: If type is updated after a matrix_params row references the plugins row, things won't be in the desired state; otherwise this works.

Comment: @kgrittn: You could add an UPDATE trigger on `plugins` (possibly with a `WHEN old.type = 'matrix' and new.type != old.type` condition if your PostgreSQL version supports it), that trigger could raise an exception if the `is_matrix` condition was violated by the update. That might be getting a bit ugly though.

Answer (score 3):

Use a compound key in the referenced table and a `CHECK` constraint in the referencing table e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE plugins (
id int primary key,
type text, 
UNIQUE (type, id)
);

CREATE TABLE matrix_params (
id int primary key,
plugintype text DEFAULT 'matrix' NOT NULL
   CHECK (plugintype = 'matrix'),
pluginid int NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (plugintype, pluginid)
   references plugins (type, id)
);
```

Comment: This changes the primary key of one table to something other than specified in the question, and adds an unnecessary column to every row in the other.

Comment: @kgrittn: I haven't changed any primary key: I've added an additional superkey to the referenced table. The added column in the referencing table enables a row-level `CHECK` constraint to be used (with a foreign key) so in context it **is** necessary. But it can be 'hidden' via a view if it bothers you.

Comment: I think it's a valid solution. When you think about it though plugintype,pluginid is not really a key because (1,'foo'),(1,'bar) should not be allowed in the plugins table. In my case I was trying to use a constant as part of the key and postgres didn't like it. I preferred the selected answer because it did the job without having to modify the data types.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  I guess I should wait for the caffeine to kick in before posting in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

One way of handling this is to use serializable transactions.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI#FK-Like_Constraints

Comment: Well, this can't be a foreign key without some denormalization (redundantly storing data in matrix_params) or declaring as IMMUTABLE a function which is really STABLE, which carries certain risks.  (When you lie to the database, it tends to get even with you sooner or later.)  So the only *really* accurate answer would be that it can't be done.  But that's not very helpful.  This is a very common type of use-case, and exactly the sort of thing serializable transactions are intended to address.  Maybe my link should have been here: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI#FK-Like_Constraints