# Adding constraint to a table referencing a subset of records of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

Say I have the following tables:

```
User(user_id, name, age,...)
Job(job_id, salary, user_id)
```

I want to have a constraint on `Job` so that whenever the job's salary is > 20,000, the user doing the job must be of age >= 18. I have tried the `CHECK` constraint but it seems to work on single table only?

Comment: You need to use a trigger defined to fire before or instead of insert, and use that to do the check and allow/disallow the insert.

Comment: Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135754/how-to-make-a-foreign-key-with-a-constraint-on-the-referenced-table-in-postgresq?rq=1) for using user defined function with check constraint, this might help in your case

Comment: why you delete I already have an answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a user-defined function.  The function can look up the value in the other table.

I'm not necessarily recommending this approach.  For many applications, I wrap insert/update statements in a stored procedure/function and put the logic there.  However, this is possible without a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

That's correct, check constraints work on single table only.
You've to use Trigger procedure to block the unwanted data, refer the below link on Trigger Procedures.

[Postgresql Documentation - Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)